'j + 1' out of bound, even after adding boundary conditions
I was doing a median of 2 sorted arrays.
'j + 1' out of bound, even after adding boundary conditions.
i = (l + r) // 2
j = half - i - 2

Aleft = A[i] if i >= 0 else float("-infinity")
Aright = A[i + 1] if (i + 1) < len(A) else float("infinity")
Bleft = B[j] if j >= 0 else float("-infinity")
Bright = B[j + 1] if (j + 1) < len(B) else float("infinity")



if (j + 1) < len(B) only protects against j being too big to be a valid index; you aren't checking if it is too small.  Perhaps half has a much smaller value than you intended?  We have no way of knowing, since you didn't post a [mcve].
